# Adding fields in KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug, keystonejs

there is any way to add new fields like tags or list of strings for each post? I want to make something with more filters. There is any tutorial on how to post and read in DB? This Jade is so weird for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your model to have any fields you like.

```
Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    tags: { type: String}
});
```

Check the docs [here](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/) to see how to create, delete and update items in DB

And if you don't like jade you can use custom view engine.
To use handlebars you need to require it first

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
```

and then add this to keystone.init..

```
    'custom engine': handlebars.create({
        layoutsDir: 'templates/views/layouts',
        partialsDir: 'templates/views/partials',
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        helpers: new require('./templates/views/helpers')(),
        extname: '.hbs'
    }).engine
```